# setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component even if component is mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react latest version, I receive the following error when click a button which run `expandMenu()`

Here tracing the lifecycle:

```
constructor
componentWillMount
render
componentDidMount
componentWillReceiveProps
render
componentWillReceiveProps
render
componentWillReceiveProps
render
expandMenu <<< click on the button - boom error!
```

AFAIK the component is mounted when running `expandMenu()`, which make the error to be ambiguous. What could cause the problem and how to fix it?

> setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This
>   usually means you called setState() on an unmounted

```js
export class Menu extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
 showPath: true,
 selectedItemIdx: 1,
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: Props) {
    const { items } = nextProps
    this.setState({
      selectedItemIdx: items.length - 1,
    })
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.debug('componentWillMount')
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.debug('componentDidMount')
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.debug('componentWillUnmount')
  }

  expandMenu = () => {
    console.debug('expandMenu')
    const { items } = this.props
    if (items.length > 1) {
      this.setState({ showPath: true }) // error here
    }
  }

  itemClickHandler = (idx: number) => {
      this.expandMenu()
  }

  render() {
    console.debug('render')
    const { classes } = this.props
    return (
          <div className={classes.root}>
                <ButtonBase
                  className={classes.title}
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.itemClickHandler(idx)
                  }}
                >
              ))}
        
          </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: And you don't get an error when you set state in `componentWillReceiveProps` then? How odd...

Comment: no errors in any other life-cycle, only onClick

Comment: According to a comment [here](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/887) - "My warning has gone away after I found the external factor forcing a re-render.
if your component re-renders several times, you need to check through carefully internally (if you have setState) and externally (redux/parent component/etc) what is causing it."

Comment: It appears there are a lot of re-renders, maybe it's a red herring and something else is causing issues which creates an ambiguous warning at a later point?

Comment: here `this.itemClickHandler(idx)` what is idx.It seems  `undefined` here. But  must be not the reason of your  issue.

Comment: Why you don't use `expandMenu` in your onClick instead of `this.itemClickHandler(idx)` .. and what's this `idx` by the way ?

Comment: I can't imagine that has anything to do with it. I think the weirdest thing is that, if it _is_ unmounting, it's not doing a console log saying so.

Comment: just notice, if I install an older version of react 15.5.4, code ti works. error happens only in the latest version of rect

Comment: as previous comments suggested, it is caused by re-renders, are you using `debounce` or `setInterval` somewhere in you component or in other parent components?

Comment: Interesting about React versions. Perhaps you could open this as an issue on Github, if you believe it to be a regression? Or perhaps they're just stricter with their warnings.

Comment: Is `<ButtonBase />` from a package incompatible with latest react version ? Maybe try with default `<button />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was related to `react-hot-loader` I had to remove it from my project dependencies.